# SQLITE ERROR:Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Iam delevoping Android app with local database.I need to get Highscore of a every user individually.I tried some code below to get user score in Textview

**EDIT : CREATE DATABASE**

```
 // Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Mydatabase.db";

private static final String TABLE_REGISTER= "register";
public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
public static final String KEY_FIRST_NAME = " first_name";
public static final String KEY_LAST_NAME = "last_name";
public static final String KEY_EMAIL_ID="email_id";
public static final String KEY_MOB_NO = "mobile_number";
public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
public static final String KEY_SCORE="score";



public static final String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_REGISTER + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_FIRST_NAME + " TEXT,"+ KEY_LAST_NAME + " TEXT,"+ KEY_EMAIL_ID + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_MOB_NO + " TEXT," + KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT ," + KEY_SCORE +
         " INTEGER)";

 @Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_REGISTER);
  // Create tables again
    onCreate(db); }

void addregister(RegisterData registerdata)
// code to add the new register
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_FIRST_NAME,registerdata.getfirstName()); // register first Name
    values.put(KEY_lAST_NAME, registerdata. getlastName() ); // register last name
    values.put(KEY_EMAIL_ID, registerdata.getEmailId());//register email id
    values.put(KEY_MOB_NO, registerdata.getMobNo());//register mobile no
    values.put(KEY_PASSWORD, registerdata.getPassword());
    values.put(KEY_SCORE,registerdata.getScore());

    // Inserting Row

    db.insert(TABLE_REGISTER, null, values);

    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
```

**EDIT:**

***Below code is used to get single highscore***

```
public int getScoreByUsername(String username){
    int highscore = 0;
    String[] col=new String[]{"MAX ( " + KEY_SCORE + ") AS Max_Score"};
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor=db.query(TABLE_REGISTER,col,
             "email_id=?",new String[]{username},null,null,null,null);
    if(cursor.getCount()<1){
        cursor.close();
        return  0;
    }
    else if(cursor.getCount()>=1 && cursor.moveToFirst()){

        highscore = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_SCORE));
        cursor.close();

    }
    return highscore;

}
```

*Below code it to used to display highscore in textview*

**MAINACTIVITY**

```
highscorelabel.setText(String.valueOf(db.getScoreByUsername(username)));
```

But iam getting **java.lang.IllegalStateException Error**.Here my logcat

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
                  at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetLong(Native Method)
                  at android.database.CursorWindow.getLong(CursorWindow.java:511)
                  at android.database.CursorWindow.getInt(CursorWindow.java:578)
                  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getInt(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:69)
                  at com.example.mathu.loginregister.DataBAseHandler.getScoreByUsername(DataBAseHandler.java:201)
                  at com.example.mathu.loginregister.ResultActivity.onCreate(ResultActivity.java:69)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6847)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2677)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2785) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1532) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6342) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:880) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:770)
```

Comment: By any chance do you have to call `moveToFirst()` before you can use `getCount()`?

Comment: @Shawn  Since iam new to sqlite can you briefly explain it

Comment: There's not much else to explain. I don't know if the android sqlite bindings require you to call `moveToFirst()` before other methods and figured it would be wroth a shot. But on second glance, your exception is being thrown from a method whose source you didn't show... you should fix that.

Comment: The issue is not in the **getScoreByEmail** method, it's in the **getScoreByUsername** method, as per `at com.example.mathu.loginregister.DataBAseHandler.getScoreByUsername(DataBAseHandler.java:201)` . Edit your question to include the **getScoreByUsername** method. (*at a guess the column name from **getColumnIndex** method has been passed a name that is not a column in the cursor*, that's a frequent cause of -1 for a column (getColumnIndex is case sensitive even though it shouldn't be)).

Comment: @shawn, not an issue getCount can be called before any move (I believe it traverses the cursor to ascertain the count).

Comment: I have edited the code as getScoreByUsername but same Error continues...Please help me @MikeT

Comment: Continuing on, the getScoreByEmail method would also result in the same error. the reason is that a Cursor only has the column names that you specified to extract. it does not have the column names as per the table(s). As you are effectively saying `SELECT max(score) AS Max_Score FROM register WHERE email_id=the_value_passed` then the Cursor will have just one column and that will be named **Max_Score** (hence there is no score column and thus the -1 from the **getColumnIndex**).

Comment: I need to get Highscore of user so i have used Max keyword to extract max values of score column .I have  initialized score column as `SELECT max( + KEY_SCORE +)`  @MikeT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you are trying to get data from a column that does not exist in the Cursor.

Change

```
highscore = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_SCORE));
```

To

```
highscore = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("Max_Score"));
```

The reasoning is explained by the comment :-

> Continuing on, the **getScoreByEmail** method would also result in the
>   same error.
>
> The reason is that a Cursor only has the column names that
>   you specified to extract.
>
> The Cursor does not have the column names as per the
>   table(s) used as it's source (*although it can e.g. `SELECT *` says get all columns from the table(s)*). 
>   As you are effectively saying `SELECT max(score) AS Max_Score
>   FROM register WHERE email_id=the_value_passed` then the Cursor will
>   have just **one column** and that will be named **Max_Score** (hence there is
>   no **score** column and thus the -1 from the getColumnIndex).

#### Additional

P.S. the method could be simplified to :-

```
public int getScoreByUsername(String username){
    int highscore = 0;
    String[] col=new String[]{"MAX ( " + KEY_SCORE + ") AS Max_Score"};
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor=db.query(TABLE_REGISTER,col,
             "email_id=?",new String[]{username},null,null,null,null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        highscore = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("Max_Score"));
    }
    cursor.close();
    return highscore;
}
```

- i.e. you only need to check the `moveToFirst`, if the count is less than 1 then `moveToFirst` will return false.

### Working example base upon your code

The following is a working example using your code with some gaps filled in. The result (albeit that there is only 1 row per user) shows that the code works.

That is the log contains (as expected) :-

```
Mary's High Score is 70000
Fred's High Score is 50000
```

In the MainActivity it has :-

```
    RegisterData fred = new RegisterData("Fred","Bloggs","fred@bloggs.email","0000 000 000","mypassword",50000);
    RegisterData mary = new RegisterData("Mary","Smith","marysmith@emailcom","0000 000 000","mypassword",60000);
    mary.addScore(10000);
```

This is then followed by (adds the 2 rows to the register table):-

```
    MyDBHlpr.addregister(fred);
    MyDBHlpr.addregister(mary);
```

Which is then followed by (to retrieve the High Score according to the EmailId and then output the values to the log) :- :-

```
    int mary_max_score = MyDBHlpr.getScoreByUsername(mary.getEmailId());
    int fred_max_score = MyDBHlpr.getScoreByUsername(fred.getEmailId());
    Log.d("HIGHSCORES","Mary's High Score is " + String.valueOf(mary_max_score));
    Log.d("HIGHSCORES", "Fred's High Score is " + String.valueOf(fred_max_score));
```

The code in full is :-

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DBHelper MyDBHlpr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MyDBHlpr = new DBHelper(this);

        RegisterData fred = new RegisterData("Fred","Bloggs","fred@bloggs.email","0000 000 000","mypassword",50000);
        RegisterData mary = new RegisterData("Mary","Smith","marysmith@emailcom","0000 000 000","mypassword",60000);
        mary.addScore(10000);

        MyDBHlpr.addregister(fred);
        MyDBHlpr.addregister(mary);

        int mary_max_score = MyDBHlpr.getScoreByUsername(mary.getEmailId());
        int fred_max_score = MyDBHlpr.getScoreByUsername(fred.getEmailId());
        Log.d("HIGHSCORES","Mary's High Score is " + String.valueOf(mary_max_score));
        Log.d("HIGHSCORES", "Fred's High Score is " + String.valueOf(fred_max_score));
    }
}
```

**DBHelper.java** (note includes some debugging code, see below)

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Mydatabase.db";

    private static final String TABLE_REGISTER= "register";
    public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_FIRST_NAME = " first_name";
    public static final String KEY_LAST_NAME = "last_name";
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL_ID="email_id";
    public static final String KEY_MOB_NO = "mobile_number";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
    public static final String KEY_SCORE="score";



    public static final String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_REGISTER + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_FIRST_NAME + " TEXT,"+ KEY_LAST_NAME + " TEXT,"+ KEY_EMAIL_ID + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_MOB_NO + " TEXT," + KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT ," + KEY_SCORE +
            " INTEGER)";

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_REGISTER);
        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db); }

    void addregister(RegisterData registerdata)
// code to add the new register
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_FIRST_NAME,registerdata.getfirstName()); // register first Name
        values.put(KEY_LAST_NAME, registerdata. getlastName() ); // register last name
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL_ID, registerdata.getEmailId());//register email id
        values.put(KEY_MOB_NO, registerdata.getMobNo());//register mobile no
        values.put(KEY_PASSWORD, registerdata.getPassword());
        values.put(KEY_SCORE,registerdata.getScore());

        // Inserting Row

        db.insert(TABLE_REGISTER, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    public int getScoreByUsername(String username){
        int highscore = 0;
        String[] col=new String[]{"MAX ( " + KEY_SCORE + ") AS Max_Score"};
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor=db.query(TABLE_REGISTER,col,
                "email_id=?",new String[]{username},null,null,null,null);
        //<<<<<<<<<< DEBUG CODE
        Log.d("CURSOR COUNT","There are " + String.valueOf(cursor.getCount()) + " rows in the Cursor.");
        logAllRows();
        //<<<<<<<<<< END OF DEBUG CODE
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            highscore = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("Max_Score"));
        }
        cursor.close();
        return highscore;
    }

    //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED METHOD TO SHOW ALL DATA IN THE REGISTER TABLE
    public void logAllRows() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor csr = db.query(TABLE_REGISTER,null,null,null,null,null,null);
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);
        csr.close();
    }
}
```

**RegisterData.java** (created based upon your code, although the **addScore** method was improvised)

```
public class RegisterData {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String EmailId;
    private String MobNo;
    private String Password;
    private int Score;

    RegisterData (String firstName,
                  String lastName,
                  String EmailId,
                  String MobNo,
                  String Password, int Score) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.EmailId = EmailId;
        this.MobNo = MobNo;
        this.Password = Password;
        this.Score = Score;
    }

    RegisterData (String firstName,
                  String lastName,
                  String EmailId,
                  String MobNo,
                  String Password) {
        new RegisterData(firstName, lastName, EmailId, MobNo, Password, 0);
    }

    public String getfirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setfirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getlastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setlastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmailId() {
        return EmailId;
    }

    public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
        EmailId = emailId;
    }

    public String getMobNo() {
        return MobNo;
    }

    public void setMobNo(String mobNo) {
        MobNo = mobNo;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return Password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        Password = password;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return Score;
    }

    public void setScore(int score) {
        Score = score;
    }

    public void addScore(int score) {
        Score = Score + score;
    }
}
```

As such, intrinsically your code that you have shown is fine. The issue with retrieving 0 must lie elsewhere. It could be that you are getting no rows.

However, some code has been added to the DBHelper class, which you could copy, which should at least split the problem between being an issue with adding the data to the table or it being an issue with the data in the table.

There are 2 parts to the dubegging code, both are added to the **getScoreByusername** method.

The first part prints the number of rows extracted, you would expect it to be 1. If it is 1 and the max_score is 0 then the issue must be that the score column is 0, null or a value that cannot be converted to a number (thus 0 is used) by the **getInt** method. If it's 1 then the second part should give an indication of the issue.

using the example above resulted in :-

```
09-16 10:12:18.618 1535-1535/? D/CURSOR COUNT: There are 1 rows in the Cursor.
```

The second part extracts all rows/columns from the table and uses the DatabaseUtils **dumpCursor** method to display the data in the cursor.

This, for the example above (a row for Fred and a row for Mary), would look like :-

```
09-16 10:12:18.618 1535-1535/? I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@5345b12c
09-16 10:12:18.622 1535-1535/? I/System.out: 0 {
       id=1
       first_name=Fred
       last_name=Bloggs
       email_id=fred@bloggs.email
       mobile_number=0000 000 000
       password=mypassword
       score=50000
    }
    1 {
       id=2
       first_name=Mary
       last_name=Smith
       email_id=marysmith@emailcom
       mobile_number=0000 000 000
       password=mypassword
       score=70000
    }
    <<<<<
```

As you can see the score column for Fred has 50000 and the score column for Mary has 70000.

If the first debug shows that 1 row was selected then it is likely that the score will not be a valid number and hence the 0.

If the first debug shows 0 then it may be that the email_id column is not as expected.

Comment: Thanks it works. your great .But I am getting score as 0 in textview ?? @Mike T

Comment: Is username (as passed to the method) a value that would be in the email_id column? Odds on no row could be found and hence the 0. Another possibility is that there is no data in the table.

Comment: My Score column is still NULL.Iam geeting score as 0 @MikeT

Comment: Ya it passing By `registerData.setEmailId(username);` in Mainactivity @MikeT

Comment: @PadmaPriya  if score is null then the issue is probably when inserting the data into the table. You need to check the value used in the line `values.put(KEY_SCORE,registerdata.getScore());` (if hard coding a number e.g. `values.put(KEY_SCORE,10000);` works then the issue is in the RegisterData class or the use of a RegisterData object)

Comment: @PadmaPriya I've amended the Answer to include a working example that basically shows that the code you have shared is good. It also includes some code that could be used to assist in debugging the issue you now have.

Comment: thank you soo much..it works..I forgot to add `db.addregister(registerdata);` .High Score for each user id displaying individually but i have trouble in getting Email Id throughout program.If User Press a button to Play a game again.User Email Id is passing as NULL .How I can achieve it  @MikeT

Comment: @PadmaPriya the example shows an example as per `int mary_max_score = MyDBHlpr.getScoreByUsername(mary.getEmailId());`. That is you need to have the Registerdata object for the current user (e.g. build/populate it when then login.)