# Couldn't read row 305, col -1 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it

Tags: java, android, contacts, android-cursor

```java
 Cursor c = activity.getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC ");
try{
                photo = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_PHOTO_URI));
                Log.d("PHOTO_URI",photo);
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("ERROR_LOG",e.toString());
            }
```

ERROR_LOG always returning `Couldn't read row 305, col -1 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.` I was reading [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52352288/16897106). According to that answer what I understood that is, that user was fetching only single column. But I am not doing that here. I am fetching all the columns from CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI. So my question is completely different from that. I had tried with `c.getInt` but it also doesn't work.

Comment: did you check the column index is right ??

Comment: @D_K As far as I know, Yes!